# Stripe incomplete payment in iOS ionic

Tags: xcode, firebase, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

I have developed an app in ionic which uses Stripe as a payment gateway. The checkout works perfectly in the local and online server, but when I build the app for iOS, the payment is never processed. According to Stripe, the payment is incomplete because the client did not specify a payment method.

```js
},
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "payment_method": null,
  "payment_method_options": {
    "card": {
      "installments": null,
      "network": null,
      "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
    }
  },
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card"
  ],
```

However, the app checkout does show the card that is being used to make the payment. In addition, while it is possible to add a different payment method with the web app, in the iOS build, it also gets stuck loading.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds themselves in the same situation, the solution that I found is the next one:

Add the following lines to your config.xml, after adding them I removed and the added again the iOS platform.

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*.stripe.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*.stripe.network/*" />
```